# scrolling a scrollView inside of a textView delegate

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, keyboard, uitextviewdelegate

I have a UIScrollView and contextView.  I add UITextViews to it and set the delegate to self so that I can use the textViewShouldBeginEditing method.  The textViewShouldBeginEditing is inside the same ViewController.m file, so the VC should be the delegate.

The textViewShouldBeginEditing method gets called and I want to check if the keyboard is blocking the textView and scroll it up if it's being blocked.

I want to call:
 [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x, y) animated:YES];
However scrollView is not seen in textViewShouldBeginEditing.

I've seen where KVO can be used, but I want to use the delegate methods.

How can I gain access to the scrollView that the textView is on?

Answer (score 1):

You can use IQKeyboardManager. Just drag and drop library to your project and eveerything will managage itself. here is the github link for that. [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager). Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, that looks interesting, I downloaded it and will try it out.   I'm still wanting to learn how to message from a delegate to another VC.  It's not just about this keyboard issue, there's something about ObjC messaging I'm missing.